# Line stippling with OpenGL ES

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to implement a line stipple (dashed/dotted line) with OpenGL ES2.0 and found many threads about this topic. But there weren't any examples. Has someone done this before and can help me with implementation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for stippled lines in OpenGL ES, so the common approaches are:

- Render multiple distinct line segments, each segment rendering one solid part of the stipple pattern.
- Render a thin quad made out of two triangles and apply the line stipple effect using a transparent texture.

From a performance point of view I'd recommend the latter if you have a significant number of lines on screen.

Comment: I think the latter also gives you better control over the line thickness and antialiasing.

Comment: I understand the first approache, which is very math heavy and very difficult for my problem, becauce I have some different elements like a circle. But I don't understand the second approache. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Option three, beyond those given by solidpixel, is to use a textured line; the fragment shader for a line can receive varyings and sample textures just like any other fragment shader. So supply a texturing coordinate as a varying running from `x = 0` to `x = k * (length of line)`, then sample your texture to produce a fragment colour.

The behaviour on OpenGL when rendering a line is different from that when rendering a quad: a thin quad on a diagonal can miss fragment centres, whereas a line will always paint a continuous collection of fragments.

So it's more or less the difference between computing the stipple on the fly versus precomputing it and looking it up. If you can compute it as you go, as solidpixel advocates, that's likely preferable as it'll consume less bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks, this option works for simple lines. But when I try to stipple two lines (by passing three position vertices) the texturing doesn't work because it's related to the first line. The second line doesn't have a constant stipple pattern.

Comment: I think it'd be fine as long as the texture coordinate at each point is calculated from the total distance along all the lines in the strip up to that point. So keep a cumulative total as you generate the geometry.